# Enabling AWS Config with CloudFormation does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-config

I registered my delegated administrator account for my AWS organization successfully (I get the notification that I´m the delegated admin every time when I´m at the StackSet Console).
[image: Evidence that I´m the delegated admin]

So I should be able to enable AWS Config with the sample template provided by AWS in the whole organization. But everytime when I run the Stackset I got the following error:

> Cancelled since failure tolerance has exceeded

As I couldn´t find any more log information or similar provided by AWS I´m really confused what I´m missing.

StackSet Config
[image: StackSet Config]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

In stack instances tab look for stacks that failed and debug them separately.

Comment: I did, but everyone has the same error message which I described above and the status is 'outdated'. Unfortunately AWS doesn´t provide much log information here.

Comment: Go to any of provisioned account to CloudFormation panel you should see stacks provisioned by stackset. Go to events in stack and check errors there